# Is there a simple way to make 4-bit discrete multiplexer?

Tags: transistors, multiplexer

I want to make a simple discrete 4-bit multiplexer using just transistors and resistors. It would take in 4 inputs and have 16 outputs, one for each binary number. However, I really don't want to make it with 16 AND gates, with 4 inputs each, as this would use up a lot of transistors. Is there a simpler way to make it?

Comment: This question is kind of vague to be honest. Welcome to digital electronics where everything is done with a lot of transistors.

Comment: `4 inputs and have 16 outputs` ... not a multiplexer ... that is a 1 of 16 decoder ... a demultiplexter can be used for this

Comment: _"I really don't want to make it with 16 AND gates, with 4 inputs each, as this would use up a lot of transistors."_ - One transistor for each output, plus 4 transistors to invert (or not invert) each input, for a total of 20 transistors. That is too many? What will you use this 'multiplexer' for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler way.

With the 4 inputs, generate the inverse of each. Now for each of the 16 outputs connect 4 transistors in series; each driven from either the input, or the inverted input according to the binary pattern of its particular code. For instance, output #7 is 0111 (inputs 3,2,1,0), so drive one transistor from input 3 inverted (the '0'), and the other transistors directly from each other input (inputs 2,1,0 respectively).

There is a way to save about ½ the transistors in this circuit by sharing all outputs driven from each polarity of the input, but it is generally slower and more complex to wire up.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you want 4 inputs and 16 outputs, may be you want a 4:16 decoder and not a multiplexer. Also, decoder is based on AND logic. So, even if optimization of number of transistors might be possible at circuit level, you have to use AND logic itself to realize a decoder circuit.